# If a Florida Homeowners Association was dissolved in 1997 for not filing Annual Rpt with FL Division of Corporations, can they enforce rules in 2024?

Tags: florida

A homeowners association has not filed Annual Reports since May 1996 with Florida Division of Corporations nor have they filed any rules with the County Clerk’s Office since that year.

According to Sunbiz.org, the HOA is inactive and received an Administrative Dissolution for Annual Report in September 1997.

How are they legally able to function as an HOA enforcing rules when they’ve not been following Florida Law for going on 28 years?

Are there any penalties involved for the HOA for this?

Comment: In regards to the votes to close due to requesting specific legal advice. This isn't asking for specific legal advice. They're asking for advice regarding a specific set of circumstances that might just apply to something very relevant to them, thus this is a perfectly cromulent question.

Answer (score 5):

A failure to file annual reports doesn't invalidate the recorded documents for the HOA. So, the legal obligations created by the governing documents of the HOA persist even if there isn't an entity to enforce them.

The HOA might have legally become an [unincorporated non-profit association](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/what-an-unincorporated-nonprofit-association.html) if it has continued to operate, as a result of its failure to file annual reports, even though it is no longer a non-profit corporation. But, [Florida has no statute expressly authorizing them](https://www.legalzoom.com/articles/how-to-start-a-nonprofit-in-florida), even though they are widely recognized at common law in other states that do not authorize them by statute.

One Florida court case considering the issue of unincorporated non-profit entities in the state said:

> We shall attempt to lay to rest some of the evident confusion
> regarding unincorporated associations whose functions are fraternal or
> social as opposed to business or profit. The latter are governed by
> partnership law. The former are a legal enigma in Florida. Although we
> can talk about them, define them, pledge allegiance to them and
> contribute money to them (often for tax deductions), we cannot sue
> them. We can only attack their members, *Johnston v. Albritton*, 101
> Fla. 1285, 134 So. 563 (Fla.1931). Until the legislature chooses to
> change the legal status of unincorporated fraternal or social
> associations, we must operate within the strictures of established
> law.
>
> The individual members of an unincorporated association are personally
> liable for tortious acts which they individually commit or participate
> in, or which they authorize, assent to, or ratify. 6 Am.Jur.2d,
> Associations and Clubs § 48; 4 Fla.Jur.2d, Associations and Clubs §
> 13. Although mere membership in a voluntary association does not make all the members liable for acts of their associates done without their
> knowledge or approval, *Sweetman v. Barrows*, 263 Mass. 349, 161 N.E.
> 272, 62 A.L.R. 311 (1928), a member may be liable without personal
> participation in the tortious act if he “sets the proceedings in
> motion or agrees to a course of action which culminates in wrongful
> conduct.” *Feldman v. North British & Mercantile Insurance Company*,
> 137 F.2d 266, 268 (4th Cir.1943). *See also, Libby v. Perry*, 311 A.2d
> 527 (Me.1973). In other words, the liability of a member of an
> unincorporated fraternal or social association is based upon his
> direct, active negligence, whether it takes the form of an act or a
> failure to act. It is not a liability imputed to the member based
> solely on his relationship to an active tort-feasor. It is not
> “vicarious liability.”

*Guyton v. Howard*, 525 So. 2d 948, 956 (Fla. 1st Dist. App. 1988).

If it is an unincorporated non-profit association, then it can't bring suit in an entity name:

> At common law, unincorporated associations were treated as
> partnerships. See, e.g., Florio v. State of Florida, 119 So.2d 305,
> 309 (Fla. 2d DCA 1960); Guyton v. Howard, 525 So.2d 948 (Fla. 1st DCA
> 1988). A partnership (and therefore an unincorporated association)
> could sue or be sued only in the name of its members, not in the name
> of the partnership. The Florida legislature has since empowered
> partnerships to sue or be sued in their own name.  § 620.8307(1), Fla.
> Stat. (1995). The association asserts that section 620.8307(1) of the
> Revised Uniform Partnership Act (RUPA) should be extended to confer
> standing on unincorporated associations because the common law rule
> that unincorporated associations are to be treated like partnerships
> has not been abrogated by statute.1 We disagree.   The legislature
> clearly intended RUPA to apply only to for-profit organizations: “An
> unincorporated nonprofit organization is not a partnership under RUPA,
> even if it qualifies as a business, because it is not a ‘for profit’
> organization.” Uniform comment to § 620.8202(2), Fla. Stat. (1995).
> The association, as its title implies,2 is not a for-profit
> association, as it was organized only to recover damages for its
> members, not to conduct business for profit.
>
> Because there is no statutory authority conferring on the association
> the capacity to sue,3 the common law rule, that associations cannot
> sue or be sued in their own name, applies in this case. Accordingly,
> the association does not have capacity to sue. Moreover, the court
> properly denied leave to amend, as the association's capacity defect
> cannot be cured. Only the individual members or a properly certified
> class would have standing under these circumstances. Because the
> capacity issue is dispositive, we need not address the standing issue. . . .
>
> 3 “An unincorporated ... association has no legal existence and
> generally does not have the capacity to sue or be sued as an entity;
> thus in the absence of an enabling or permissive statute conferring
> associational standing, such an association must sue or be sued in the
> names of the individuals composing it rather than its firm name.” Fla.
> Jur.2d, Associations and Clubs § 15 (1994) (citing *Hunt v. Adams*,
> 111 Fla. 164, 149 So. 24 (1933); *Johnston v. Albritton*, 101 Fla.
> 1285, 134 So. 563 (1931); *I.W. Phillips & Co. v. Hall*, 99 Fla. 1206,
> 128 So. 635 (1930); *Guyton v. Howard*, 525 So.2d 948 (Fla. 1st DCA
> 1988); W*alton–Okaloosa–Santa Rosa Medical Soc. v. Spires*, 153 So.2d
> 325 (Fla. 1st DCA 1963); *Florio v. State*, 119 So.2d 305 (Fla. 2d DCA
> 1960)).

*Asociacion De Perjudicados Por Inversiones Efectuadas En U.S.A. v. Citibank, F.S.B.*, 770 So. 2d 1267, 1268-1269 (Fla. 3d Dist. App. 2000)

*But see Seaside Town Council, Inc. v. Seaside Community Dev. Corp.*, 347 So. 3d 89 (Fla. 1st Dist. App. 2021) (holding that a non-profit corporation comprised of nine neighborhood associations within an unincorporated beach-front development had standing to sue the developer and county). This case also observes in a a footnote that: "**It is also worth noting that a property manager has standing to sue on behalf of the entity it represents.**" *Id*. at 96.

In a worst case scenario for the HOA, a court could hold that it does not have the power to sue or be sued as a dissolve entity, until its dissolution if cured or it is reincorporated.

But, the HOA's non-profit corporation could cure its administrative dissolution (possibly paying the unpaid annual filing fee for 27 years at perhaps $50-$100 a year), or it could reincorporate itself. So, challenging the failure to file annual reports, while it might be a procedural bump in the road for the association that would cause it to incur a few thousand dollars of remedial corporate legal work and might delay the case a little, probably wouldn't prevent it from acting in the long run.

It is also fairly likely that the HOA has long ago reincorporated and that the new HOA formed after the old one was dissolved simply has a slightly different name and has been missed in a search of corporate records, or that it acts through a property manager or proxy non-profit that acts on its behalf.

Footnote: The case law on unincorporated associations has a wonderful case name for an appeal which summarily affirmed a trial court ruling in a single word, per curium, without a reasoned decision:

> DONALDSON ENGINEERING, INC., a Florida Corporation, and Vulcan
> Construction Company, Inc., a Florida Corporation, Appellants, v.
> Russell S. BATCHELDER, as Exalted Ruler of the Titusville Lodge Number
> 2113, Benevolent and Protective Order of Elks, U.S.A., a voluntary
> unincorporated association, not for profit, et al., Appellees

*Donaldson Engr., Inc., v. Batchelder*, 304 So. 2d 564 (Fla. 4th Dist. App. 1974).

Comment: But aren’t HOAs bound by law to follow FS 720?

Comment: So Homeowner builds a fence with unapproved materials and refuses to pay HOA fines or remove the fence. It sounds like you're saying the HOA could fairly easily restore itself to *sui juris* to enforce its fines or its rules, but would it have a valid claim? I definitely know nothing about this area of the law, but if I parachuted in, I think my first argument would be that none of the rules approved since 1997 have any legal force.

Comment: @bdb484 Perhaps, but this is not at all an obvious conclusion. The fact that an unincorporated nonprofit or one not in good standing can't sue doesn't imply that it can't conduct other business with the authority granted to it from the recorded governing documents.